# Corrupted Heap error c

Tags: c, heap-corruption

I am trying to create a tree from a vector of parents. However I get a "corrupted heap error" when I create the nodes with malloc. It works for the first two children , however crashes on the third(or terminates but does not connect the root with the child.)

> Unhandled exception at 0x77E8A879 (ntdll.dll) in lab7.exe: 0xC0000374:
>   A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77EC5910).

I have implemented this by, first extracting the root and creating the node and after that extracting the children of the root and creating them.

search root-> searches for the root and returns the value of it.
the function that searches  for the  children(search key )

void create->The function that creates the children. I send a vector that contains only the children of that specific parent and not other children.

```
 *typedef struct  node
    {
        int value;
        node *left;
        node *right;
        node *middle;
    }TreeNodeParent;
    int search_root(int in[9])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (in[i] == -1)
            {
                int var = i+1;
                in[i] = -2;
                return var;
            }// pe else nu facem nimic
        }
        return -2; 
    }
    int search_key(int in[9], int  radacina)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (in[i] == radacina)
            {

                int var = i + 1;
                in[i] = -2;
                return var;
            }
        }
        return -3;
    }
    TreeNodeParent *createOneNode(int value)
    {
//the error appears here
        TreeNodeParent* create = (TreeNodeParent*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNodeParent));
        create->value = value;
        create->left = create->middle = create->right = NULL;
        return create;
    }

    void create(int vector[], TreeNodeParent* radacina)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (vector[i] == -3)//am stabilit ca -3 ii oprirea
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                TreeNodeParent* create = createOneNode(vector[i]);

                if (radacina->left == NULL)
                {
                    radacina->left = create;
                }
                else if (radacina->middle == NULL)
                {
                    radacina->middle = create;
                }
                else 
                {
                    radacina->right = create;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        int input[9] = { 2,7,5,2,7,7,-1,5,2 };
        int root = search_root(input);
        if (root == -2)
        {
            printf("Nu gasim radacina, arbore incorect!");
        }
        else { printf("root %d", root); }

        //crearea nodului parinte
        TreeNodeParent* rootParent = (TreeNodeParent*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNodeParent*));
        rootParent->value = root;
        rootParent->left = NULL;
        rootParent->right = NULL;
        rootParent->middle = NULL;
        int vect2[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)//worst case, tot arborele is copii ai lui root->o(n2)
        {
             vect2[i] = search_key(input, root);
             printf("copii rootului %d", vect2[i]);
            if ( vect2[i] == -3)
            {
                break;
            }
        }   
        create(vect2,rootParent);
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

checked online with gdb :

> ```
> >     tin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((ol
> >     d_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
> program exited
> > with code 134
> ```

I can't understand why the function crashes only on the third(and not before). Also it does not always appear. Sometimes it works fine, other times it stops with that error. 
Also If there is a better way to create a tree with a parent representation?

Comment: You have typo here radacina->right == create; you might want it to be radacina->right = create;

Comment: Yes, thank you! However the error appears on the createOneNode function.

Comment: Then the problem is not in the posted code. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, stack or heap? They are entirely different things. A heap corruption you'll notice when you call `free()` and get a program crash. A stack corruption will result in random behavior and will be caused by something like recursion, stack overflow, runaway code or pointer bugs.

Comment: Avoid images in questions. Provide some [MCVE] in text form. Compile with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)..). Improve the code to get no warnings. Use a debugger (like [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)) and a dynamic heap-analysis tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). You should **edit your question** to improve it a lot

Comment: The Visual Studio version I have runs in debugger mode(if I switch to release the exception does not appear at any time, It;s only in the debugger mode.I ).

Comment: the picture says heap, but you speak of stack. Please correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `main()` method, where you `malloc()` with `sizeof(TreeNodeParent*)` instead of `sizeof(TreeNodeParent)` and assign it to `rootParent`:

```
//crearea nodului parinte
//TreeNodeParent* rootParent = (TreeNodeParent*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNodeParent*));
TreeNodeParent* rootParent = (TreeNodeParent*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNodeParent));      `
```

Comment: I'll take a look at that, thank you! However, I am not sure if in sizeof should be (TreeNodeParent*)  or (TreeNodeParent).

Comment: `sizeof(TreeNodeParent*)` is just the size of a pointer to a `TreeNodeParent` struct (4 or 8 bytes depending on your architecture) and not the size of entire struct. So for example `sizeof(int*), sizeof(long*)` or `sizeof(TreeNodeParent*)` are all the same. If you like the size of the entire struct use `sizeof(TreeNodeParent)`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the difference!